# Is it possible to load a URL and zoom in 150% by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I only have some URLs here, and I would like to load these URL and zoom in them by 150% by default.

Maybe I can create a html wrapper to load these URL dynamically and use something like

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5"/>
```

to zoom in them? But I am not sure how exactly to do it and if it will work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What type of URL?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are you embedding urls as iframes? if so, the iframe source page needs to have that meta info.

Comment: Thank you! One defect of iframe is: it has cross domain issue, which causes many internal links not navigatible. I wonder if there is any other similar functionality to create a wrapper?